# How difficult would it be to add a message on 1000+ html files?

Tags: html, message

I have over 1000 html files that I need to edit in the exact same way. I need to;

1. Add a simple javascript code at the top of each file.
2. Put some kind of message at the top (it can be anything, as long as it displays the message I want it to).

I was wondering, do I have to edit each file manually to do this? Is there not .htaccess hacks or anything like that?

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider using a CMS.. now might be a good time.

Comment: Some text and code editors have possibilities to bulk edit files.

Comment: I don't envy you, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I you are using linux, or have installed [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on windows, then [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) may be the quickest way to edit the files.

Combined with find, it can be used to very quickly add (or indeed edit) many files.

For example, the following command will replace all instances of the word 'old' with 'new' in all .html files:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i "s/old/new/g" '{}' \;
```

There are *many* other examples online.

Comment: +1, though I'd have mentioned a regex replace as a general solution that works out of the box in pretty much any modern language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to autoprepend some code, but to be honest, a global find/replace would be a better idea in many ways.

I don't know what OS you use, but as a Mac Developer, http://www.hexmonkeysoftware.com/ is a neat little tool that does find and replace over loads of files.

Otherwise, a quick python script would be easy to write to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, is there any program I can use for Windows 7?

Comment: Not sure, never really used Windows mainly due to the lack of decent software for developers.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any common structure to the files, and their content is valuable and going to be used further in some way, then I would consider going the opposite route and extracting all that information, storing it in a database (or something) and presenting it like normal. This would provide more flexibility in presentation, and could even make the data useful/usable in other ways.